# Initialize script in componentDidMount – runs every route change

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am working on a navbar for my react app (using gatsbyjs to be precise). In the navbar I have a marquee that I initialize in the navbar component in `componentDidMount`.

It works as intended, but upon every route change `componentDidMount` will run again which results in the marquee speeding up for every page change, making it go faster and faster.

Is this expected behaviour? And if so, how do I make sure that the script is only run once?

**navbar.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import styles from '../styles/navbar.module.css';
import NewsMarquee from './newsMarquee';
import Marquee3k from 'marquee3000';

const topLevelNav = [
  {
    href: '/news',
    label: <NewsMarquee/>,
    extraClass: styles.navLinkNews,
    mediaQueryClass: styles.navLinkHiddenSmall,
  },
];

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Marquee3k.init();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className={styles.navbar} role="banner">
          <nav className={styles.nav}>
            {topLevelNav.map(({ href, label, extraClass = '', mediaQueryClass = '' }) => (
              <Link
                key={label}
                to={href}
                className={`${styles.navLink} ${extraClass} ${mediaQueryClass} ${menuItemsHidden}`}
                activeClassName={styles.navLinkActive}
              >
                {label}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**newsMarquee.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import styles from '../styles/newsMarquee.module.css';

export default () => (

  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC } limit: 10) {
          totalCount
          edges {
            node {
              id
              frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "YYYY.MM.DD")
              }
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <div className={`marquee3k ${styles.marquee}`}>
      <div>
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
        <span className={styles.marqueeItem} key={node.id}>
          {node.frontmatter.date} {node.frontmatter.title}
        </span>
      ))}
      </div>
      </div>
    )}
  />
)
```

Comment: Does `Marquee3k` have a way to uninitialize? If so you'd have to call it in `componentWillUnmount` to clean up.

Comment: @SungKim It does not. But even if it did, I suppose destroying and then running it again would cause a jump/stutter in the marquee effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using GatsbyJS I went with [this plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/) from V1, which makes my layout component persist across pages.

**gatsby-plugin-layout**
This plugin enables adding components which live above the page components and persist across page changes.

This can be helpful for:

- Persisting layout between page changes for e.g. animating navigation
- Storing state when navigating pages
- Custom error handling using componentDidCatch
- Inject additional data into pages using React Context.

This plugin reimplements the behavior of layout components in gatsby@1, which was removed in version 2.